# C# Backgroundworker report progress for 2 progress bars?

Tags: c#, winforms, backgroundworker

I have several large files that I'm processing and I'm using the `backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(percent)` to report the progress as each file is finished.  But now I want to have a second progress bar to report the progress for each individual file as it's being processed (and resets for the next file).  I can use the current byte position I'm reading from and divide by the total size of the file to get the progress in percentage.  But how do I pass this value to progressBar2 if there's only one ProgressChanged event?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way is to use [BackgroundWorker.ReportProgress(Int32, Object)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a3zbdb1t.aspx) and pass whatever you want, in the userState parameter.

Another is to simply know that when you've reached 100% on the first progress bar you need to increment the other bar.

Answer (score 3):

ReportProgress has an [overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a3zbdb1t.aspx) which allows you to pass an extra object. You can use this to return any extra state you need.

```
public void ReportProgress(
    int percentProgress,
    Object userState
)
```

You can then read the state from [`ProgressChangedEventArgs.UserState`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.progresschangedeventargs.aspx).